# phpunit: catchable fatal error when testing

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit

I am working on Zend framework , i have set up everything but in the unit testing i get a fatal error:

c:\xampp\htdocs\zend\module\Album\test>phpunit
PHP Catchable fatal error: Arugment 1 passed to Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::__construct() must be of the type array, object given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\module\Album\test\Bootstrap.php on line 53 and defined in c:\xampp\htdocs\zend\vendorframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php on line 144

Bootstrap.php Line 52-58:

```
    $config = ArrayUtils::merge($baseConfig, $testConfig);
    $serviceManager = new ServiceManager(new ServiceManagerConfig());
    $serviceManager->setService('ApplicationConfig', $config);
    $serviceManager->get('ModuleManager')->loadModules();

    static::$serviceManager = $serviceManager;
    static::$config = $config;
```

ServiceManager.php Line 144-148:

```
  public function __construct(array $config = [])
    {
       $this->creationContext = $this;
       $this->configure($config = []);
    }
```

Some advice please???

Answer (score 1):

```
$serviceManager = new ServiceManager(new ServiceManagerConfig());
```

> Arugment 1 passed to Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::__construct() must be of the type array, object given

The error is telling you that `ServiceManager` expects an array as an argument. The argument you are passing is `new ServiceManagerConfig()`, which is an object.

It's a version mis-match.

In `zendframework/zend-servicemanager` `~2.0` the `ServiceManager` constructor requires an object.

In `zendframework/zend-servicemanager` `~3.0` the `ServiceManager` constructor requires an array.

If you are using the [zf skeleton application](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/releases), make sure you are using the correct version.

Comment: Thank you for your reply... so what do I need to change to fix this mis-match ??

Comment: If you're using composer then make sure it's requiring the version you want. It looks like you probably need version ~2.0, but it really depends on your project.

Comment: I have followed these steps , and i cannot find out where i went wrong 
https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/unit-testing.html

Comment: Make sure you are reading the latest docs for version https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/user-guide/overview.html. Somehow you managed to install version 3 of zend-servicemanager when the docs seem to be based on version 2.